# Synchronously connecting to a socket in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple node js server and I would like to connect to another socket, read data, and return it to the client.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
     var sock = new Socket();
        sock.connect(80, "www.google.com", function(){
            console.log("Connected to google..");
            sock.write("GET /\r\n\r\n");
        }); 
        sock.on("data", function(data){
            console.log(data.toString()); 
            res.writeHead(404, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
            res.write(data, "binary");
            res.end(); 
            sock.end();
        });
        sock.on("end", function(){
            console.log("Disconnected from socket..");
        }); 
}, 8080);
```

But this obviously doesn't work because the call to data callback is asynchronous.

So how can I accomplish this with node js?

Comment: What is wrong with the asynchronous callback?

Comment: Can you tell more what happens when you run this ?

Comment: So it sounds like your basically trying to write a proxy server?

Comment: The code needs to send data it receives as part of a different routine. Yes, you could say it works like a proxy server. I solved it by storing the received data inside a temporary buffer variable which is read inside the server callback when another connection arrives. This however means that the data can never be returned right away (for example I would like to read google.com and return the page content right away), but instead the user needs to issue one http request for initiating the connection and then polling it by sending subsequent http requests to get the data.

Comment: There's no reason you can't return the data right away. Just send the data from the the "data" callback to the response, and then close the response in the "end" handler.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the missing "require" statements and the server.listen() call to get the script to run, it works fine for me:

```
var http = require('http');
var Socket = require('net').Socket;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
     var sock = new Socket();
        sock.connect(80, "www.google.com", function(){
            console.log("Connected to google..");
            sock.write("GET /\r\n\r\n");
        }); 
        sock.on("data", function(data){
            console.log(data.toString()); 
            res.writeHead(404, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
            res.write(data, "binary");
            res.end(); 
            sock.end();
        });
        sock.on("end", function(){
            console.log("Disconnected from socket..");
        }); 
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Ideally I would want the server response callback to wait until the call to google finishes before returning an http response to the user.

Comment: Okay, then you move the res.end() call to the sock.on("end") handler.